# Command add-in on calender item screen for Office 365

Tags: office365

I'm trying to create a command addin for Office365.  This should create a button on the calender item form.  Ideally both online and in the Outlook program.

I'm trying to use the Yeoman Office Project Generator.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office

I select:

```
- Appointment attendee
```

and then

```
Add buttons to: (Press <space> to select)
❯ Default tab
```

This is the manifest file that was created: http://pastebin.com/tpXs3Dkv

I believe this should add buttons to the form but I don't see any, although I have added the add-in.

I would like the button to appear here:
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s29/sh/42e2d473-fc76-49d1-ba5c-164e84308e45/fb981692359f71b9986f68b6ac25e91a

Is this something that is possible or doesn't MS support this?

I also tried this sample project: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-BillMaker but that one too doesn't create any buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You will find you add-in when you click the Add-ins button, it'll show up on the TaskPane.

[image]

Like below,

[image]

Comment: Hi Jackie, thanks for your reply.  I got the Add-ins button as well, but I was expecting Command button to appear on the panel.  For example next to Categorize.  Why isn't this the case?

Comment: Add-in commands are currently limited to Outlook 2013 and 2016; they aren't implemented yet in Outlook Online